# ExtJS 4 consuming server response

Tags: web-services, extjs, extjs4

I'm working with extjs4 in a very large **legacy** web application, and trying to figure out how to tie my view to a particular sub-object inside a store that handles a web services proxy. The webservice will provide an object like so:

```
foodOrder = {
  result: {

        date : 02/11/2013,
          orderId: 123456,

          fruitProducts: {
            melons: {
               water,
               cantelope,
               ...
            },
            apples: {
               delicious,
               granny smith,
               ...
            }
          }
        }
  }
```

The store receiving this response looks like this:

```
Ext.Define('MyApp.model.FoodOrder', {
  extend: 'Ext.Model',

  fields: [
    {name: 'date', type: 'date'},
    {name: 'orderId'},
    {name: fruitProducts, type: 'array'}
  ],

  proxy: {
    type: 'mycustomproxy',
    url: 'the/food/store/order',
    reader: {
      root: 'result',
      totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    }
  }
});
```

What are some strategies I can take to "dig into" the `fruitProducts` parameter inside the result? If I wanted to load my view with the information found in the webservices response, how would I do that? Is there some way to filter through the response?

Any ideas/thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` config property on the reader can be changed to refer to your deeper content. The [Ext docs say this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-root) about `root`:

> For JSON reader it's a property name (or a dot-separated list of property names if the root is nested).

So, you should be able to use something like this:

```
reader: {
    root: 'result.fruitProducts',
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But what if some other components are using this Store, and only one of my views needs access to fruitProducts? I cannot change the root in this case, because it will break other areas. Subclass?

Comment: Sure, you could create subclasses of the store that replace the reader's root.